# App's main window freezes, resize helps: how to diagnose the issue?

Tags: windows, debugging, graphics, mfc

*Note: this is not a newbie question*

Main window of my application occasionally "freezes" with symptoms listed below. The application continues to work properly as soon as main window resized.
Debuggers, Windows Application Verifier and other tools I used revealed no problems.

What could be a reason or how can I check why the window becomes blocked from updates?

Some details:

- old 32-bits c++ MFC application, worked fine for many years on many Window XP installations in 24/7 mode
- the app renders some simple 2D graphics with MFC/GDI functions
- on several computers under 64-bits Windows 7, very rarely (~once per  month) app's main window stops updating: it looks exactly as if the app took a screenshot of client area of its main window and shows this screenshot until mail window resized
- my diagnostic logs and all kind tools indicate that once frozen, internally the app works normally: it still renders updates but because of some reason Windows ignores them
- application main menu opens and works properly
- all drawings are made in single thread
- various modal dialogs called via main menu also work properly
- Notepad brought on top on my app shows properly and leaves no traces behind
- Windows itself and all other application always work properly

I would think this is something related to the video card/its driver we are using (3 monitors connected to two NVIDIA NVS 300) but I don't understand why only my application is affected. Also I would love to know with what magic the resizing removes the update lock.

**Update 12/9/2015**:

- I'm sure the drawing thread is not blocked: it is application main thread that also always properly responds to mouse clicks, menu commands and keyboard
- All counters (memory, processor, GDI/USER objects) indicate no problems

Comment: There's not a lot to go on here. It may benefit you to provide some example code or specific diagnostics. I would think whatever redrawing code you use would be most useful. Stack Overflow prefers specific questions and this one leads to a lot of "how to debug" answers that would be rather broad.

Comment: If the window freezes and appears to wake up on a resize/menu operation, it is a strong indication, that your message loop has stopped processing messages. Starting moving/sizing/menu operations enters into a modal message loop, implemented by the system. It is a nested message loop that starts processing messages again. The same happens with modal dialogs. I do not understand (and cannot explain), why the application appears to work as expected internally. What sort of logs are you generating?

Comment: I would check the number of the GDI handles at the time of that freeze in the Task Manager. In 24/7 app, even a slow leak may exhaust the available handles. This may not be a leak, but just lazy release of allocated resources.

Comment: @Vlad Feinstein, this is what I checked first. All counters are OK

Comment: @IInspectable, I'm sure the loop is running: it still responds to mouse clicks, opens those modal dialogs, processes WM_TIMER messages

Comment: @ToothlessRebel, the specific question is: what kind block can prevent an app from drawing on its own window

Comment: Does your code use WM_SETREDRAW message and/or calls to LockWindowUpdate()?

Comment: @Vlad Feinstein, no, it does not. And I have checked MFC sources if it uses them in some circumstances but found nothing related to my case.

Comment: Do all of the failing machines use Aero theme? If yes - could you change one of them to Windows Classic and see if this is a DWM's fault?